# DynamoDB: can't use multiple AND operators combined with ORDER BY on sort key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, partiql

I believe I've found a bug in DynamoDB using PartiQL.

Given this table:

```
  name      = "my-table"
  hash_key  = "device_id"
  range_key = "message_id"

  attributes = [
    { name = "device_id", type = "S" },
    { name = "message_id", type = "S" },
    { name = "timestamp", type = "N" },
  ]

  local_secondary_indexes = [
    {
      name            = "device-id-timestamp-local-index"
      hash_key        = "device_id"
      range_key       = "timestamp"
      projection_type = "ALL"
    },
  ]
```

I can't use the following PartiQL SELECT Statement:

```
SELECT * FROM "my-table"."device-id-timestamp-local-index" WHERE device_id = "91f66b0e-1565-431b-aa4a-5db301af9510" AND "timestamp" >= 1689552000000 AND "timestamp" <= 1689724799999 ORDER BY "timestamp" DESC
```

Throws the following error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the ExecuteStatement operation: Must have at least one non-optional hash key condition in WHERE clause when using ORDER BY clause.
```

I believe this is a Bug because the following PartiQL SELECT Statements work:

```
SELECT * FROM "my-table"."device-id-timestamp-local-index" WHERE device_id = "91f66b0e-1565-431b-aa4a-5db301af9510" AND "timestamp" >= 1689552000000 ORDER BY "timestamp" DESC
```

```
SELECT * FROM "my-table"."device-id-timestamp-local-index" WHERE device_id = "91f66b0e-1565-431b-aa4a-5db301af9510" AND "timestamp" >= 1689552000000 AND "timestamp" <= 1689724799999
```

So by putting multiple AND operators in the Sort key and using ORDER BY, we get the above error.

Comment: If you want anyone to be able to help you, you might want to say what the "weird error" actually was.

Comment: It's already described in the question: `An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the ExecuteStatement operation: Must have at least one non-optional hash key condition in WHERE clause when using ORDER BY clause.`

Comment: Does the query work with the AND condition but without the ORDER BY?

Comment: And try `timestamp BETWEEN 1689552000000 AND 1689724799999`.

Comment: @jarmod that was perfect. BETWEEN works like a charm, and to answer your question, it worked without the ORDER BY, it was the last example in my original question.

Comment: @jarmod Do you want to answer this question so that I can mark your answer as Correct?

Comment: Out of interest, can you retry your query as follows: `SELECT * FROM "my-table"."device-id-timestamp-local-index" WHERE device_id = '91f66b0e-1565-431b-aa4a-5db301af9510' AND timestamp >= 1689552000000 AND timestamp <= 1689724799999 ORDER BY "timestamp" DESC`. Note that I've surrounded the device ID value with single quotes instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original query was:

```
SELECT * FROM "my-table"."device-id-timestamp-local-index" \
    WHERE device_id = "91f66b0e-1565-431b-aa4a-5db301af9510" \
    AND "timestamp" >= 1689552000000 \
    AND "timestamp" <= 1689724799999 \
    ORDER BY "timestamp" DESC
```

I can't immediately explain why the range condition doesn't work, perhaps it's a PartiQL bug, but the following works:

```
SELECT * FROM "my-table"."device-id-timestamp-local-index" \
    WHERE device_id = "91f66b0e-1565-431b-aa4a-5db301af9510" \
    AND timestamp BETWEEN 1689552000000 AND 1689724799999 \
    ORDER BY "timestamp" DESC
```

Note that `BETWEEN X AND Y` is inclusive of both X and Y values.